# Create custom key binding for VSCode with args pre-defined

Tags: visual-studio-code

#### Summary

I am trying to create custom key bindings for Microsoft Visual Studio Code. When I invoke one of the VSCode commands, I would like to specify arguments, so that I am not prompted to select an item from a list.

**Example Use Case**: I want `SHIFT+ALT+X` to delete a Docker container image named `alpine`.

Take a look at the `vscode-docker` extension for VSCode, which has a registered command named `vscode-docker.images.remove`. Here is the [command definition from GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/blob/master/src/commands/images/removeImage.ts). As you can see, it has a `node` and `nodes` argument. I assume that if I pass in a value of `alpine` for the `node` argument, that it will simply delete the `alpine` container image.

```js
export async function removeImage(context: IActionContext, node?: ImageTreeItem, nodes?: ImageTreeItem[]): Promise<void> {
  .............
}
```

The command is [registered with VSCode in this file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/blob/master/src/commands/registerCommands.ts).

The documentation for VSCode doesn't describe how to discover VSCode commands or arguments for those commands, so I went into the source code for the `vscode-docker` extension to find out.

#### What I've Tried

I've tried using the following configuration in `keybindings.json`.

```json
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "SHIFT+ALT+X",
        "command":"vscode-docker.images.remove",
        "args": {
            "node": "alpine"
        }
    }
]
```

#### Expected Result

The selected Docker image is removed / deleted from the system.

#### Actual Result

I get a popup in the lower-right corner of the VSCode window saying:

```
This action is invalid for some selected items. These items will be ignored.
```

[image]

A Google search for `"This action is invalid for some selected items"` yields zero results. It seems I am the first person to come across this error and post about it online.

**Question**: How do I properly pass in args into the `vscode-docker.images.remove` command?

Answer (score 0):

It arguments need to be `TreeItems`.

The command is [connected to a button on a line in a TreeView](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/blob/40be20f4fa40342d77b2dcd596d7f49c41a169cf/package.json#L444).

Looking at the source of `vscode-docker.images.remove` passing in a string (`name`) does not work.

Or the function `registerCommandAzUI` from `vscode-azureextensionui` must do some name to TreeItem transform.